# Why does button image revert after user clicks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I change my buttons image in viewWillAppear with this code

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"button_preference"]];

Button.imageView.image =buttonImage;
```

but when its clicked on it reverts to the image set in IB. So I tried to add

`[leftButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

bu then the image doesn't change in the first place?

Comment: You can try to change the Button.imageView.image to [Button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; you can set an image to button using setBackgroundImage: forState: method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
Button.imageView.image =buttonImage;
```

and

```
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Both are different because first one is set image as imageView of button and second is set image as background of button so i'm not sure but issue should be either overlaying of image of `button.imageView`  or your second code has not image *(i mean NULL)*;

My opinion is that set button image such like

```
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is better for you.

Comment: Okay well so I removed the image from IB and made it a backround image and used the code to change the backround image instead of the image and everything is working great. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIImage.setImage method:

```
[leftButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or in Swift

```
leftButton.setImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```